# i18n Angular 5 change translations

Tags: angular, internationalization, command-line-interface, translation, aot

i have an Angular 5 CLI project. He works, but I don't know how to change the local by the website. If I want an English translation, I have to use this command:

```
ng build --aot --locale en --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/Ressources/translations/messages.en.xlf --missing-translation error
```

Or this command for a French translation:

```
ng build --aot --locale fr --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/Ressources/translations/messages.fr.xlf --missing-translation error
```

Etc... 
However, I have to make this change by a combo box and I don't have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AOT, after you compile your project for en and fr you should serve in your nginx(or the http server you are using) an instance for each language, for example if your domain is: mydomain.com, it should be served smething like this: mydomain.com/en and mydomain.com/fr. Then in your combobox, you just redirect to the desired translation.

Comment: tank you for your response but if i use "dotnet run" instead of ng serve, is it the same principe?

Comment: If you do a "ng build" you do not need to run or serve the project when deploy it, you serve directly the output dist folder with your http server (nginx for example), you need to read the docs about JIT and AOT. https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler |

Comment: your link have a 404 error yet but tank you, i will make my research about it